# useSelector returns undefined state(however state is set)

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am creating a project which is a copy of Twitter(X). I am implementing state management using REDUX, and persisted login using redux-persist. I store user's username and token in redux(for best practice) and local storage
I have several pages namely home and profile which render profile page and PostList respectively.
The problem I am facing is related to the usage of useSelector on Home and Profile pages. When I try to retrieve token from state using useSelector, it returns undefined, the same happens with username.
I console logged state, checked Redux DevTools, everything seems to be in order there and state receives the correct values, however I can't retrieve them for some reason.

P.S. I have checked other similar cases on Stack, but none of them provide a solution for my problem.

Here is the code for Profile page:

```
'use client'
import { IconButton, Typography, Avatar, Button } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import moment from 'moment';
import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth';
import ProfileHeaderCategories from '../components/ProfileHeaderCategories';
import { selectAuthToken,selectAuthUser } from '../store/selectors/authSelectors';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

let registrationDate = moment().format('[Joined] MMMM Do YYYY').toString()

const backgroundImageUrl = "/"

const Profile = () => {
    const username = useSelector(selectAuthUser);
    const token = useSelector(selectAuthToken)

    console.log(username, token) // returns undefined

    return (
        <main className='border-r-[0.5px] border-r-gray-600 w-[600px] max-w-[650px]'>
            <div className='flex items-center pl-2 mb-2'>
                <Link href="/home">
                    <IconButton sx={{
                        padding: 1,
                        marginTop: 1,
                    }}
                        className='hover:bg-[#293640] mr-4'
                    >
                        <ArrowBackIcon
                            className='text-white rounded-full text-[20px] font-bold'
                        />

                    </IconButton>
                </Link>
                <Typography variant="h6" className='font-bold'>
                    {username}
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <Image src={backgroundImageUrl} alt="Background Profile pic" width={500} height={500} />
            <div className='flex justify-between'>
                <Avatar sx={{
                    width: 120,
                    height: 120,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
                    marginLeft: 2,
                }}
                    className='border-4 border-[#15202b]' />

            </div>
            <Button className='text-white font-bold bg-[15202b] rounded-full border-gray-600 capitalize float-right'
                sx={{
                    border: 0.5,
                    borderColor: "gray",
                    marginTop: 1,
                    marginRight: 1,
                    padding: 1,
                }}
            >Edit profile</Button>
            <div className='flex flex-col mt-16'>
                <span className='px-4 font-bold text-xl'>{`Your name`}</span>
                <span className='text-gray-400 text-base px-4'>{username}</span>
                <div className='text-base text-gray-400 pt-4 px-4 mb-4'>
                    <CalendarMonthIcon sx={{
                        fontSize: 'medium',
                        marginRight: 1,
                    }} />
                    {registrationDate}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='border-b-[0.5px] border-b-slate-500'>
                <ProfileHeaderCategories />
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}


export default Profile
```

Code for authReducer and store // separate files:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authReducer= createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    username: null,
    token: null,
    showSignIn: true,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUsername: (state, action) => {
      console.log('Before set name:', state.username);
      state.username = action.payload;
      console.log('After set name:', state.username);
    },
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      console.log('Before setting token:', state.token);
      state.token = action.payload;
      console.log('After setting token:', state.token);
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.username = null;
      state.token = null;
      localStorage.clear()
    },
    toggleShowSignIn: (state) => {
      console.log('Before toggle:', state.showSignIn);
      state.showSignIn = !state.showSignIn
      console.log('After toggle:', state.showSignIn);
    }
  }
});
export const { setUsername, setToken, logout, toggleShowSignIn } = authReducer.actions;
export default authReducer.reducer;
```

```
'use client'
import { configureStore, combineReducers  } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postSlice from "./slices/postSlice";
import signUpReducer from "./reducers/signUpReducer";
import signInReducer from "./reducers/signInReducer";
import authSlice from "./slices/authSlice";
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { PersistPartial } from "redux-persist/es/persistReducer";
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'



// RootState type to include persisted state
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer> & PersistPartial;

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'signData',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['auth'],// only the 'auth' reducer in persisted state
};

// Combine reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: postSlice,
  signUpForm: signUpReducer,
  signIn: signInReducer,
  auth: authSlice,

});

// Create persisted reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
})
})

export default store;
```

Code for selectors:

```
import { RootState } from "../store";
export interface UsernameAuth {
    username: string
}
export interface TokenAuth {
    token: string
}

export const selectAuthUser = (state: UsernameAuth) => state.username;
export const selectAuthToken = (state: TokenAuth) => state.token;
export const selectShowSignIn = (state: RootState) => state.auth.showSignIn;
```

I tried writing down useSelector function a bit differently like:
const tokenCheck = useSelector((state) => selectAuthToken(state))
it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

your selectors should look like

```
export const selectAuthUser = (state: RootState) => state.auth.username;
export const selectAuthToken = (state: RootState) => state.auth.token;
```

like you're doing with the `showSignIn`, Or even better:

```
export const selectAuthUser = ({auth}: RootState) => state.username;
export const selectAuthToken = ({auth}: RootState) => state.token;
```

`useSelector` returns the global state from the redux store

Comment: Could you explain that please?
export const selectAuthUser = ({auth}: RootState) => state.username;
export const selectAuthToken = ({auth}: RootState) => state.token;

Comment: It's a javascript ES6 expression called [Object destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)